# ASP.NET MVC: Multiple language for textual content in script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to implement multiple language in my ASP.NET MVC project. I use resource files to localize the textual contents in server. What is the best approach to implement the localization in client-side textual content (content written by JQuery)? Should I send all the resource files to client-side and go from there? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If the localization content in client-side is from resource file, you have to create special controller for reading resource files and output the content into JSON format, so that it can be easily called in your js code.

for example:

and in the controller, output content as Json:
Res={
 "key":"value"
}

then you can use the content by  Res.key

BTW, you can use plain text file to localize the textual contents in server, not resource files : http://wangweiqiang.net/a-localization-approach-with-json-data-for-net-application/